# Align two buttons at the bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4's [card groups](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#groups). I want to align both buttons at the same line which should be at bottom of the .card.

[image]

The [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/44Lnjj8d/4/).

I tried

```
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;    // <- if I use absolute here, it will be ugly
  bottom: 0;
}
```

and also

```
.card {
  display: table;
}

.btn {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

But neither works.

Comment: why do you think positioning absolute will be ugly..??

Comment: @Nareshsadu because I tried it, everything will become not organized any more when use `absolute` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would something like this work for you ?

https://jsfiddle.net/44Lnjj8d/5/

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform:: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the card-block height and the buttons will show after the block.

https://jsfiddle.net/44Lnjj8d/6/

```
.card-block {
  height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: it looks a promising way, is it possible to not give a fixed height?